# microsoft/fetch-event-source API for NodeJS is working on local computer but on Azure onmessage(msg) is not functioning

Tags: node.js, azure, fetch-api

I am using below code module inside my API Call:

```
await fetchEventSource('/api/chat', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          question,
          history,
        }),
        signal: ctrl.signal,
        onmessage(event) {
          if (event.data === '[DONE]') {
            setMessageState((state) => ({
              history: [...state.history, [question, state.pending ?? '']],
              messages: [
                ...state.messages,
                {
                  type: 'apiMessage',
                  message: state.pending ?? '',
                  sourceDocs: state.pendingSourceDocs,
                },
              ],
              pending: undefined,
              pendingSourceDocs: undefined,
            }));
            setLoading(false);
            ctrl.abort();
          } else {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data.sourceDocs) {
              setMessageState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                pendingSourceDocs: data.sourceDocs,
              }));
            } else {
              setMessageState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                pending: (state.pending ?? '') + data.data,
              }));
            }
          }
        },
      });`
```

and the API is responding back with the data but once it enters `onmessage(event) { if (event.data === '[DONE]') {` logic on Azure the onmessage is not functioning , on my local environment its validating the onmessage and event data. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

````
onmessage(msg) {
        // if the server emits an error message, throw an exception
        // so it gets handled by the onerror callback below:
        if (msg.event === 'FatalError') {
            throw new FatalError(msg.data);
        }
    },
```above code segment is functional locally on local node but not on Azure. Local Node version 18.15.0 & Azure is on 18.12.0
````

Comment: Hello, @Malatesha Somasundar Anantha could please tell from which Azure service you are reading the message and Azure deployment  details

Comment: Hi @Sampath, i am reading the data from my api running on azure /api/chat utilizing fetchEventSource, and the API is responding back with Data, but on the client from where i am making the api call using fetchEventSource , there the onmessage property is not doing anything like it does in my local dev environment where it recognize the event data and log it. Azure deployment was made through Github. Its a App service with Windows os, Node 18.12.0. everything else is working the ui , api call and server response , but after response the onmessage of azure fetchEventSource  is not functioning.

Comment: This could be a server side issue as well. I have noticed that Azure Front Door doesn't support HttpClient Streaming. Make sure to check in that direction as well.